# How to disable adding a program to Sonos favorites?

Tags: sonos

In a `getMetadata` call, I'm returning a `mediaCollection` with `itemType=program`. I don't want it to have the "Add Station to My Sonos" option. So I tried returning it with `canAddToFavorites=false` but it doesn't change a thing. The "Add Station to My Sonos" option is still there.

http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/286

> canAddToFavorites boolean (Optional, default=true) The collection can be added to user favorites.

How do I disable this option if it's not with `canAddToFavorites`? Does it only work for some specific `itemType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `canAddToFavorites` is a marker to disable the ability for a user to add the item to the PARTNER favorites. In other words, if Acme Music Service has their own notion of a list of favorited tracks/albums/stations, a user can, from inside the Sonos app, save an item to that list. This flag conditionally prevents that. So it has nothing to do with "My Sonos". Currently there is no way to prevent an item from being added to My Sonos, unless you mark it as `isEphemeral`.